# Wacom digital pen works after booting but not after screen unlocked again

Tags: wacom

I am using Wacom Intuos Pro S on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop. After startup I run some applications like Xournal++ where I use my pen to take handwritten notes. After booting my pen works finely. If I leave the computer unattended for some time and the screen is unlocked again, my pen does not work any more. How can I reactivate my digital pen without rebooting the computer? The terminal command "xsetwacom --list" returns:

```
Wacom Intuos Pro S Finger touch     id: 12  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Intuos Pro S Pen stylus       id: 10  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos Pro S Pen eraser       id: 11  type: ERASER    
Wacom Intuos Pro S Pen cursor       id: 17  type: CURSOR    
Wacom Intuos Pro S Pad pad          id: 18  type: PAD
```

The pen still seems to be recognized. How do I reactivate the digital pen so that I can use it again?

Thanks

Comment: try xinput then xinput enable <id number of your pen from xinput>
another approach xinput map-to-output <pen id>  <monitor/touchscreen name from xrandr>

Comment: Running xinput and xinput enable <id> and unplugging and replugging helped. I will find out later on what it depended exactly. Maybe I formulate an answer myself in the days to come. Previously, simply unplugging and replugging the tablet had not been helpful.

Comment: Goodoh! can I put my comment in as an answer then?

Comment: Pierrely, sure, but let me run into this problem again, then I can analyse better how to it was actually solved. Then you can give the answer.

Comment: Pierrely, after follwoing your advice from Jun 26 the tablet works perfectly fine and the problem has not reappeared since, the problem might be alleviated completely now ... hopefully the problem has now gone away completely. You can certainly put your comment into an answer if you like.